# Prove two orthogonal contrasts are uncorrelated

Tags: anova, contrasts, orthogonal

I am reading some ANOVA notes and have a problem with proving two orthogonal contrasts are uncorrelated.

Here is what I tried:
Assume that $\bar X_i, i=1,\dots,n$ are uncorrelated. Suppose we have two contrasts
$$
C_1 = \sum_i a_i \bar X_i, \quad C_2 = \sum_i b_i \bar X_i, \quad 
$$
We have
\begin{align*}
\text{cov}(C_1, C_2) &= \text{cov}(\sum_i a_i \bar X_i, \sum_j b_j X_j) \\ 
&= \sum_{i} \sum_j a_i b_j \text{cov}(\bar X_i, \bar X_j) \\
&= \sum_{i} a_i b_i \text{var}(\bar X_i).
\end{align*}
Hence, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are uncorrelated if and only if $ \sum_{i} a_i b_i \text{var}(\bar X_i) = 0$.

But by the definition of a contrast and orthogonal contrasts, we only know
$$\sum_{i} a_i = 0, \quad  \sum_{i} b_i = 0, \quad \sum_{i} a_i b_i =0$$
How should I go from here? Thanks!

Comment: Are your X normalized?, i.e. is variance the same for all $X_i$?

Comment: @Cryo I don't think these assumptions are given.

Comment: But then what does your $\sum_i a_i$ mean? If values are normalized then $a_i$-s are all in the same units, but if they are not, lets say $X_1$ is height in meters and $X_2$ is weight in kg, so $a_1$ is effect/meter and and $a_2$ is effect/kg. How do I add them? I would simply transform your input data by normalizing it, and then prove the theorem for the normalized values.

Comment: @Cryo The materials appear in the ANOVA section, so basically, the $\bar{X_i}$'s are different treatment group means.

Comment: That does not matter, when these things are not normalized it is not clear you can compare them, meters/kg make it very obvious, but I equally easily could have had meters->standard_deviation of the first group, kg->standard deviation of the second group. Without normalization your $a$-s have different units, so summing them does not really make sense. Irrespective of that, what stops you from re-defining $a$-s and $b$-s to be coefficients for normalized data, and then proving the theorem?

Comment: @Cryo Sorry, what does "normalized" mean?

Comment: Here, I mean that unit change in $\bar{X}_i$ is the mean divided by some common scale. Something that leads to $Var\left(X_i\right)=const$ without this I cannot easily compare the scale to which a change between two observations of $\bar{X}_1$ is more/less significant than change between two observations of $\bar{X}_2$. If I cannot do that, I cannot compare $a_1$ and $a_2$ since their contributions to the common effect depend not only on their face-values, but also on the variability of different $X_...$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150922/discussion-between-matata-and-cryo).